# When should I use capital letters after a colon?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, style

Example:

> "Your head of department called," she said. That was what I liked
>   about my mom: **S/s**he never bothered with greetings. Straight to the
>   point. "You've been absent for two weeks. What's wrong? Are you sick?"

I'm unsure whether to use **She** or **she**.

Comment: Guidance I've heard before said: Don't use a capital when the part after the colon isn't a complete sentence – use lower-case instead. However, if it could stand on its own as a complete sentence, you can use either case.

Comment: @J.R.♦ Thanks. I thought I had to use capitals when the colon "presents" more than one sentence (like my example above).

Comment: There's a pretty exhaustive rundown of "capitalisation after colon" over at [grammar.ccc](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm)